# Is using conditional accessibility label text good?

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I have this code in my React Native app that renders a list of types. Selected and not selected types have different backgrounds. Is it okay to make accessibility label text conditional?

```
<View style={styles.typesList}>
            {types.map(type => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={type}
                  style={[
                    styles.type,
                    {
                      backgroundColor: filterTypes.includes(type)
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.lightYellow
                    }
                  ]}
                  onPress={() => {
                    handleFilterTypesChange(type);
                  }}
                  testID='type'
                  accessibilityLabel={`${
                    filterTypes.includes(type) ? 'Unselect' : 'Select'
                  } ${type} filter`}
                >
                  <Text>{type}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen readers by default read-out if a checkbox is selected or not. So no need to put conditional text to just read out it. If you have multiple select boxes it is advised to use fieldsel and legend which will give details to visually challenged persons.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select your pizza toppings:</legend>
  <input id="ham" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="ham">
  <label for="ham">Ham</label><br>
  <input id="pepperoni" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="pepperoni">
  <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>
</fieldset>
```

The  contains the group of checkboxes, and the  labels the group. Screen readers may repeat the legend for each control in the group, so the legend text should be brief and descriptive.